# "a value must be provided for item" error in sharepoint cascading dropdowns in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, cascadingdropdown, powerapps

I am doing a simple cascading dropdowns in sharepoint customizing the forms using powerapps. I am restricting the values in second dropdown using the formula given below.
Distinct(Filter(CategoryandSubCategory,Title = CategoryComboBox.Selected.Value),SubCategory)
When i publish this i am able to edit existing items but not able to create new records in the list. 
Please help. I know there are other solutions but i wan't powerapps to work because most of the users are already accustomed to this approach.

Comment: What type of controls are you using: DropDown controls or ComboBox controls? I have tried the scenario that you mentioned above with DropDowns and seems to be working as expected so I want to make sure that I am not missing something. Also, in which cards did you add your dropdowns (custom / existing)?